# Count Occurrences within a for loop c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

I'm new to c++, what i'm trying to do is count the amount of times a letter occurs with a piece of text or paragraph and stores this into an array called frequency array.

The code below is working to a degree, what happens is if the user types hello frequencyarray stores 11121, if the user types aaba frequency array stores 1213
I don't want a running total i'm wanting the array to store 1121 and 31. so if the same letter appears it adds 1 to the array.

Thanks David

```
#include <iostream> //for cout cin
#include <string>   //for strings
#include <fstream>  //for files

using namespace std;

int main()
{       
    string text;

    int frequencyarray [26]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    cout << "Enter Word: ";
    cin >> text;

//***************************COUNT OCCURANCES************************

    for (int i(0); i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = text[i];

        c = toupper(c);
        c -= 65;

        if (c < 26 || c >=0)
        {
            frequencyarray[c]++;
            cout << frequencyarray[c];
        }
    }

    system ("pause");

return(0);

}`
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're outputing the contents of the array in your loop? The first time you find the letter 'a' then 1 will be printed the next time 2 and so on. Dump the array outside the loop and you will get the correct output.

Comment: You also should use `&&` in the if-statement. Right now *all* characters will qualify.

Comment: You can also use `c -= 'A';` instead of the constant `65`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the running total, don't have the `cout << freqencyarray[c];` inside the cycle that is counting the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream> //for cout cin
#include <string>   //for strings
#include <fstream>  //for files
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{       
    string text;

    int frequencyarray [26]={0};

    cout << "Enter Word: ";
    cin >> text;

//***************************COUNT OCCURANCES************************

    for (int i(0); i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = text[i];

        c = toupper(c);
        c -= 65;

        if (c < 26 || c >=0)
        {
            frequencyarray[c]++;
        }
    }

    std::for_each(std::begin(frequencyarray), std::end(frequencyarray), [](int i)
    {
         std::cout << i << ",";
    });
    std::cout << "\n";
    system ("pause");

return(0);

}
```